# How to remove last 10 elements from the list using C#?

Tags: c#

How to remove last 10 elements from the list using C#?

```
private List<FeedTextDto> _feedsItemGlobal;

public class FeedTextDto
    {
        public FeedTextDto()
        {
            Content = new List<ContentDto>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public TextType TextType { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public List<ContentDto> Content { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What solutions have you tried yourself?

Comment: How urgent can this be :).

Comment: If it was urgent you'd have bothered to supply details. We don't even know what data type you refer to.  Clearly you don't care enough to do that. -1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
if(Content.Count >= 10)
  Content.RemoveRange(Content.Count - 10, 10);
else
  Content.Clear()
```

Comment: How do you know what type the list is?

Comment: Its a sample. Not a really code.

Comment: Because in the question he says "How to remove last 10 elements from the LIST using c#. " not LinkedList

Comment: The list is in lower case. The question is imprecise.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, the question is imprecise, but it might have solved his problem. If he wanted to be precise, he would have said on the description of the question.

Comment: Now can you please help me